# Why Redis in K8S restarts all the time?

Tags: kubernetes, redis

Redis pod restarts like crazy.
How can I find out the reason for this behavior?

I figured out, that the resources quota should be upgraded, but I have no clue what would be the best cpu/ram ratio. And why there are no crash events or logs?

Here are the pods:

```
> kubectl get pods
    redis-master-5d9cfb54f8-8pbgq                     1/1     Running     33         3d16h
```

Here are the logs:

```
> kubectl logs --follow redis-master-5d9cfb54f8-8pbgq
[1] 08 Sep 07:02:12.152 # Server started, Redis version 2.8.19
[1] 08 Sep 07:02:12.153 # WARNING you have Transparent Huge Pages (THP) support enabled in your kernel. This will create latency and memory usage issues with Redis. To fix this issue run the command 'echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled' as root, and add it to your /etc/rc.local in order to retain the setting after a reboot. Redis must be restarted after THP is disabled.
[1] 08 Sep 07:02:12.153 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
[1] 08 Sep 07:03:13.085 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
[1] 08 Sep 07:03:13.085 * Background saving started by pid 8
[8] 08 Sep 07:03:13.101 * DB saved on disk
[8] 08 Sep 07:03:13.101 * RDB: 0 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
[1] 08 Sep 07:03:13.185 * Background saving terminated with success
[1] 08 Sep 07:04:14.018 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
[1] 08 Sep 07:04:14.018 * Background saving started by pid 9
...
[93] 08 Sep 08:38:30.160 * DB saved on disk
[93] 08 Sep 08:38:30.164 * RDB: 2 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
[1] 08 Sep 08:38:30.259 * Background saving terminated with success
[1] 08 Sep 08:39:31.072 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
[1] 08 Sep 08:39:31.074 * Background saving started by pid 94
```

Here is previous logs of the same pod.

```
> kubectl logs --previous --follow redis-master-5d9cfb54f8-8pbgq
[1] 08 Sep 09:41:46.057 * Background saving terminated with success
[1] 08 Sep 09:42:47.073 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
[1] 08 Sep 09:42:47.076 * Background saving started by pid 140
[140] 08 Sep 09:43:14.398 * DB saved on disk
[140] 08 Sep 09:43:14.457 * RDB: 1 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
[1] 08 Sep 09:43:14.556 * Background saving terminated with success
[1] 08 Sep 09:44:15.073 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
[1] 08 Sep 09:44:15.077 * Background saving started by pid 141
[1 | signal handler] (1599558267) Received SIGTERM scheduling shutdown...
[1] 08 Sep 09:44:28.052 # User requested shutdown...
[1] 08 Sep 09:44:28.052 # There is a child saving an .rdb. Killing it!
[1] 08 Sep 09:44:28.052 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
[1] 08 Sep 09:44:49.592 * DB saved on disk
[1] 08 Sep 09:44:49.592 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
```

Here is the description of the pod. As you can see the limit is 100Mi, but I can't see the threshold, after which the pod restarts.

```
> kubectl describe pod redis-master-5d9cfb54f8-8pbgq
Name:           redis-master-5d9cfb54f8-8pbgq
Namespace:      cryptoman
Priority:       0
Node:           gke-my-cluster-default-pool-818613a8-smmc/10.172.0.28
Start Time:     Fri, 04 Sep 2020 18:52:17 +0300
Labels:         app=redis
                pod-template-hash=5d9cfb54f8
                role=master
                tier=backend
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             10.36.2.124
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/redis-master-5d9cfb54f8
Containers:
  master:
    Container ID:   docker://3479276666a41df502f1f9eb9bb2ff9cfa592f08a33e656e44179042b6233c6f
    Image:          k8s.gcr.io/redis:e2e
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://k8s.gcr.io/redis@sha256:f066bcf26497fbc55b9bf0769cb13a35c0afa2aa42e737cc46b7fb04b23a2f25
    Port:           6379/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Wed, 09 Sep 2020 10:27:56 +0300
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       OOMKilled
      Exit Code:    0
      Started:      Wed, 09 Sep 2020 07:34:18 +0300
      Finished:     Wed, 09 Sep 2020 10:27:55 +0300
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  42
    Limits:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  250Mi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     250Mi
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-5tds9 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  default-token-5tds9:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-5tds9
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Guaranteed
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason          Age                   From                                                Message
  ----    ------          ----                  ----                                                -------
  Normal  SandboxChanged  52m (x42 over 4d13h)  kubelet, gke-my-cluster-default-pool-818613a8-smmc  Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created.
  Normal  Killing         52m (x42 over 4d13h)  kubelet, gke-my-cluster-default-pool-818613a8-smmc  Stopping container master
  Normal  Created         52m (x43 over 4d16h)  kubelet, gke-my-cluster-default-pool-818613a8-smmc  Created container master
  Normal  Started         52m (x43 over 4d16h)  kubelet, gke-my-cluster-default-pool-818613a8-smmc  Started container master
  Normal  Pulled          52m (x42 over 4d13h)  kubelet, gke-my-cluster-default-pool-818613a8-smmc  Container image "k8s.gcr.io/redis:e2e" already present on machine
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the limit after which it restarts. CPU is just throttled, memory is OOM'ed.

```
    Limits:
      cpu:     100m
      memory:  250Mi
```

`Reason:       OOMKilled`

1. Remove requests & limits
2. Run the pod, make sure it doesn't restart
3. If you already have prometheus, run [VPA Recommender](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler#quick-start) to check how much resources it needs. Or just use any monitoring stack: [GKE Prometheus](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/prometheus), [prometheus-operator](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/prometheus-operator), [DataDog](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/monitoring-kubernetes-with-datadog/#:%7E:text=The%20Datadog%20Agent%27s%20Kubernetes%20integration,metrics%20for%20detailed%20resource%20breakdowns) etc to check actual resource consumption and adjust limits accordingly.

Comment: Or just increase the memory limits to a value that fits his environment

Comment: If you remove the limits, redis will continue eating memory.
And if redis continues consuming more memory, k8s will kill the pod when the node where it is hosted runs out of memory with an "Evicted" as you can see in this response:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63857449/2275126

Therefore, this is a bad solution that only will cause more problems.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem is that you didn't limit the redis application. So redis just increases the memory, and when it reaches Pod `limits.memory` 250Mb, it is killed by an OOM, and restart it.
Then, if you remove the `limits.memory`, the redis will continue eating memory until the Node has not enough memory to run other processes and K8s kills it and marks it as "Evicted".

Therefore, configure the memory in redis application to limit the memory used by redis inside `redis.conf` file and depending on your needs set a LRU or LFU policy to remove some keys (https://redis.io/topics/lru-cache):

```
maxmemory 256mb
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lfu
```

And limit the memory of the Pod at around the double of redis `maxmemory` to give the rest of the processes and objects saved in redis some margin:

```yaml
resources:
  limits:
    cpu:     100m
    memory:  512Mi
```

Answer (score 2):

Max's answer is very complete. But if you don't have Prometheus installed or don't want to, there is another way simple to check actual resource consumption installing the [metrics server](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server#deployment) project in your cluster. After installing it you can check the CPU and memory usage with `kubectl top node` to check consumption on the node, and `kubectl top pod` to check consumption on pods. I use it and is very useful.

*Or you can just increase the CPU and memory limits, but you will not be able to ensure how much resources the container will need. Basically will be a waste of resources.*

Answer (score -1):

Now the pods are getting evicted.
Can I find out the reason?

```
NAME                                              READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
redis-master-7d97765bbb-7kjwn                     0/1     Evicted            0          38h
redis-master-7d97765bbb-kmc9g                     1/1     Running            0          30m
redis-master-7d97765bbb-sf2ss                     0/1     Evicted            0          30m
```

Comment: Can you post the kubectl describe from the evicted pods?

Comment: You should edit your first post adding this new information instead of replying yourself with more questions.

Comment: The pods are being evicted because the node of the Kubernetes cluster is running out of memory. See it in my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63829136/why-redis-in-k8s-restarts-all-the-time/71155431#comment125779493_63829780